# "Xbox Support" underneath my gamertag

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one

A friend recently brought to my attention that right underneath my gamertag on my Xbox One profile it says "Xbox Support."

Anyone know why or how this has happened, and more importantly, how to get rid of it?? I've done a few Google searches but have come up emptyhanded.

### This is what it looks like on xbox.com as well as on my dash:

[image]

Comment: Could you post an image of that tag perhaps? Or a link to your profile?

Comment: @aytimothy hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your profile says "Xbox Support", but when I look at my profile that location has my first and last name. I'm not sure where you set what your name is, but maybe if you find that you can change it from "Xbox Support"?